# css vertical input range width issue

Tags: html, css

i set a vertical input range in a div with css this way:

```
input[type=range] {transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

i dont want to use

```
appearance: slider-vertical;
```

(because it destroy my slider-design).

the div is height: 30% of the page; and width: 33px;.
I want the input range (slider control) to take the full height of the div.

I cant use {width: 100%;} (yes the slider react to it horizontal dimensions) it would make the slider 33px.

So how to set the slider width to 100% of the div height ? I'm a very beginner, is there a css simple way to do something like that but that actually working ?
(I dont see anywhere)

```
divFoo{
  height: 30%;
  width: 33px;
}

input[type=range].slider {
  width: divFoo.height;
}
```

thanks

Comment: This must be done with javascript

Comment: this kind of things ->  input[type=range].slider {width: divFoo.height;} <-- doesnt exist ?

Comment: No, it must be done with javascript. I will post a code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be done with javascript. Here is the code snippet.

```js
// We should make sure that the window is loaded first
window.onload = function() {
  // get height of div
  // we can also calculate by using
  // var height = window.offsetHeight * (30 / 100)
  var height = document.getElementById("div").offsetHeight;
  // Now we set the width of the slider to the height of the div
  document.getElementById("slider").style.width = height+"px";
};
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 33px;
  height: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Here is your div -->
<div id="div"></div>
<!-- Here is the slider -->
<input type="range" id="slider">
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! there is a little oversight in your code:                                                  var height = document.getElementById("div").offsetHeight+"px";

Comment: Whoops, my bad, lemme just edit it. Don't forget to mark it as the right answer!